# Authenticated Proxy for development purposes

Tags: proxy

I am looking for a simple solution to start a squid-like proxy server that supports username/password authentication.

It should be able to tunnel HTTPS requests using CONNECT.

Answer (score 0):

A docker-based solution is

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3128:8080 mitmproxy/mitmproxy mitmdump --set proxyauth=user:pass
```

The `--ignore-hosts` option also enables TLS pass-through for stuff like mTLS and certificates not signed by a trusted root (i.e. via. `mkcert` or self-signed).